# Can be replaced with method reference

Tags: android, lambda

I have such code, but compiler give a suggestion to replace `accounts != null` part with method reference. How can I do it? 
Maybe there is other possibilities to check that the

```
mMainApi.accounts(user, password)
            .filter(accounts -> accounts != null)
            .map(/* Something here */)
            .subscribe();
```

I have found one solution to use `.filter(Objects::nonNull)` but this solution requires Android API > 24, so this does not help actually.

Answer (score 0):

you can try below code

```
mMainApi.accounts(user, password)
            .filter(accounts ->{ 
              return accounts!=null;
            })
            .map(/* Something here */)
            .subscribe();
```